Android 5.1.1 - cannot add Google account; getting stuck on "add phone number?"
I am now trying to get my old phone to life.
This is Nexus 4 with Android 5.1.1. I have successfully restored it to the factory, now I am trying to configure it with my Google account. Unfortunately, each time I enter a password, it redirects me to the "Add phone number?" screen and I get stuck there - links "more info", "skip", and "I'm in" simply do not work. The only thing I can do is cancel the whole operation.
I also gave a try with another Google account - it also got stuck on the screen asking "Who will be using this device?".
Is there any way to configure the account?

The second symptom finally allowed me to google the solution.
I found the proper answer here.
Before logging in, I have chosen that I do not remember my login.
I have entered a valid recovery address and entered the recovery code.
Then I was able to go through the logging process (including the "add the phone?" screen) smoothly.

I have the same problem here with Android 6 on a Nexus 5. I did the trick here which worked up to the screen saying "Welcome back" then it is stuck when I tap on continue.
